# How can i connect php to arduino esp32

Tags: php, database, cpanel, arduino-esp32

I'm looking for a way to run esp32 behavior with php.

I've been googling for a few days, but couldn't find any code that works the way I want it to.

So I started to wonder if this could be possible, so I posted a question here.

---

1. Purpose

---

The figure below shows the program structure I want to implement.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPvwc.png)

A : User connects to DB server and opens php file

B : php file transmits DB data value to esp32 module connected to the same station
( I use [ WiFi.begin]  function )

---

2. What I Did

---

The picture below shows how the esp32 updates DB.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNvqL.png)

A : User connect sensor to esp32 & supply power

B : Connect to WiFi and send sensor value to PHP file in DB server storage

C : Update the data received by php to the DB table

---

3. what should i do

---

I've written down everything I've implemented and what I've been implementing.

Now I'm at a dead end and I don't know what to do.

It would be a great help if you could tell me how you know or what keywords you Google searched for.

Thank you for taking your valuable time to read this question. :D

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem or code the solution for you. Beginners are welcome, but we expect some effort from you to solve your own problem before asking a question. SO is not a free coding service, although we are very willing to help you fix issues with your written code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the esp32 'talk' with the web server holding the DB using PHP, this way you can save data from the esp32 in your DB.

The user can interact with the server and request the server to send commands to the esp32.

I have the above working some time ago, but I dont have the code and Im not in that company anymore.

Comment: thank you for your help i will esp32 talk googleing :D